# C# TextBox Form Email Object Simplification

Tags: c#

I have a huge webform with many textboxes and on client click, the data needs to be emailed to the company.

At present I am hard coding and concatenating the message body with direct references to the various textboxes, however this is a lot of typing and would be a pain in the whatsit to change.

```
string body = "Name: " + tbName.Text + "\n" ...;
```

So I have put the form into an object which has a ton of string properties and two bool (if needed could be changed to string) but I am having an issue putting all of the object's properties into a single string for the email body.

And so on, to

```
CompanyClass myObj = new CompanyClass();
myObj.Name = tbName.Text;
string body = //where I'm looking to put the object into a function as an  argument.
```

This comes from::

```
public class CompanyClass
{ 
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string ...

   public CompanyClass(string nme, ...)
   {
       Name = name;
   }
   public ObjToString(myObj)
   {
      // where I am having issue
   }
}
```

Is this possible? Speed isn't an issue as it's only one form.

Cheers.

Comment: you will have to add a lot mroe for anybodybody to understand what you are doing

Comment: is this form of type WPF or WinForms or ASP?

Comment: Through ASP sorry, updated so the user enters details and then those details are sent to where ever via email.

Comment: Why do you show the `CompanyClass`? It doesn't seem to be related at all.

Comment: ...also, if you are looking for a dynamic approach, how is the literal `"Name"` related to `tbName.Text`? What are the strong rules to identify the key and the value?

Comment: Apologies Tim had to go afk half way through an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflect across the properties of your new class and append the values together.

```
foreach(var prop in newObj.GetType().GetProperties()) 
{
    string bodyText = +=  prop.GetValue(newObj, null));

}
```

Comment: This will do! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Define array of string formats plus textbox objects, do a loop with `string.Format( all_obj[i].ToString(), ((TextBox)all_obj[i + 1]).Text )` and collect all lines. Something like:

```
StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
object all_obj[] = new object[] { "Name: {0}", tbName, ... };
for ( int i = 0; i < all_obj.Length; i += 2 )
    res.AppendFormat( all_obj[i].ToString(), ((TextBox)all_obj[i + 1]).Text );
```